# How do I use axios in vue3

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I created a project in vue2 and now I'm migrating to vue3.
I had an api service which looked like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import JwtService from "@/common/jwt.service";
import { API_URL } from "@/common/config";

const ApiService = {
    init() {
        Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
        Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;
    },

    setHeader() {
        Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common[
            "Authorization"
        ] = `Bearer ${JwtService.getToken()}`;
    },

    query(resource, params) {
        return Vue.axios.get(resource, params).catch(error => {
            throw new Error(`[RWV] ApiService ${error}`);
        });
    },
    ...
```

How do I change this to vue3. I'm not supposed to use vue.axios anymore. In the documentation it says that should use app or this. But am I then supposed to export the app from main? I can't find any examples for this